# Python CGI With Data Return

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- Pull information from a module through Python. [Accomplished]
- Constantly pull information from Python for use in HTML.
- Avoid writing the entire HTML/CSS/JS document in print statements.

I've seen the term CGI thrown around, but don't really understand how it works. Simply put, I want to run the Python script which returns an integer value. I then would like to take that integer value into JavaScript so that it may update the designated tag. It should be able to execute the Python script every two seconds, receive the output, then apply it to the page. I do not want to write out the entire HTML document in Python by doing one line at a time, as I've seen some people doing on sites I've found.

It seems like doing something like this is far more complicated than it should be. The page should run, call the script for its output, then give me the output to use.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you don't know what CGI is and find that what you ask for is "far more complicated than it should be", you first have to learn the HTTP protocol, obviously, and that's way to broad for a SO answer.

Basically what you want requires:

- an html document
- some javascript code, either linked from the document or embedded into it
- a web server to serve the document (and the javascript)
- a web server (can of course be the same as the previous one) that knows how to invoke your python script and return the result as an HTTP response (you'll probably want a json content type) - this can be done with plain CGI or with a wsgi or fcgi connector, in your case CGI might well be enough.

Then in the browser your javascript code will have to issue a GET request (ajax) every x seconds to the web server hosting the Python script and update the DOM accordingly.

This is all ordinary web programming, and as I said, a basic understanding of the HTTP protocol is the starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to write anything from scratch, if you don't know anything about the subject, is always going to be complicated.

That is why there is a whole world of tools to help you. I don't think you want CGI at all; look into one of the Python micro frameworks, in particular [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org). The tutorial there should give you the introduction you need.